# Phony targets in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu

I was trying to execute the example in this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

```
all : prog1 prog2 prog3
.PHONY : all

prog1 : prog1.o utils.o
    cc -o prog1 prog1.o utils.o

prog2 : prog2.o
    cc -o prog2 prog2.o

prog3 : prog3.o sort.o utils.o
    cc -o prog3 prog3.o sort.o utils.o
```

With or without PHONY (if i comment out the .PHONY line), the outputs are the same. What is the real use of PHONY here?

The article mentions this

`When one directory contains multiple programs, it is most convenient to describe all of the programs in one makefile`

`Since the target remade by default will be the first one in the makefile, it is common to make this a phony target named ‘all’ and give it, as prerequisites, all the individual programs`

I cant understand what is the real use of PHONY here. Can someone point me a scenario in this example in which the program would behave differently without PHONY?

Answer (score 5):

without .PHONY "all" is just a regular make target which depends on prog1, prog2, prog3. This means that if a file named "all" would happen to exist in the directory that is newer than prog1, prog2 and prog3, they will not be built (try it!) - but this is obviously not what you had in mind.

.PHONY tells GNU make the "all" target is phony - you don't REALLY intended for a file called "all" to be created and it should build the dependencies regardless if a file called "all" exists or not.

Added later:

My example with all and prog1 above was not correct although the general idea is true. Here is a much simple example

```
all: prog

prog: prog.c

clean:
  $(RM) prog prog.o


giladb@xxx:~/tmp$ ls
Makefile  prog.c
giladb@xxx:~/tmp$ make
cc     prog.c   -o prog
giladb@xxx:~/tmp$ make clean
rm -f prog prog.o
giladb@nps06:~/tmp$ make
cc     prog.c   -o prog
giladb@xxx:~/tmp$ touch clean
giladb@xxx:~/tmp$ make clean
make: `clean' is up to date.
```

Comment: Not true, at least for gnu make: `touch prog1.c ; sleep 1; touch all; make all` build prog1, as you can see file `all` exists and it is newer then `prog1.c`

Comment: @user1034749 that's because all needs to be newer than prog1 not prog1.c

Comment: But date of prog1 have no sense, if it is newer then source code. And question is about why use PHONY, if it is change nothing.

Answer (score 2):

At least for GNU Make in combination with this example the behavior regarding the output is the same, no matter if the target "all" is a phony target or not. Even if there is a file named "all".

BUT as described in the manual behind your link the internal behavior of GNU Make is different. If "all" is not a phony target, GNU Make checks whether a file named "all" exists and is older than its prerequisites. Try "make -d" and you will see the difference.

Another important point is that the recipe of a phony target is always executed. If you take this example:

```
all: goal
    echo "Done"

.PHONY : clean

goal:
    echo "Hello World!" > $(@)

clean:
    rm -f goal all
```

... and execute this:

```
$ make clean
rm -f goal all
$ make
echo "Hello World!" > goal
echo "Done"
Done
$ make
echo "Done"
Done
$ touch all
$ make
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

... the recipe will not be executed after creating the file "all".

With "all" being a phony target:

```
all: goal
    echo "Done"

.PHONY : all clean

goal:
    echo "Hello World!" > $(@)

clean:
    rm -f goal all
```

... the recipe of "all" will be executed always independent of the existence of the file "all".

```
$ make clean
rm -f goal all
$ make
echo "Hello World!" > goal
echo "Done"
Done
$ make
echo "Done"
Done
$ make
echo "Done"
Done
$ touch all
$ make
echo "Done"
Done
$ make
echo "Done"
Done
```